# Clicking outside the responsive menu closes it down well but afterwards not

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to close the nav bar and toggle the burger lines when i click outside the menu .
It all works fine the first time but after the second attempt i can't really understand what is going on .

The second time i try to close the nav bar , my function with animations doesn't get executed and also the second line of the event targeting function which should toggle my burger lines doesn't ge executed , but the first line inside the if statement which closes the nav does.

When i click outside the nav bar , it always closes but only at the second attempt toggles the burger lines as well.

My code is here https://codepen.io/bunea-andrei/pen/jOBGNgd?editors=1100 .

Also i'll leave the JavaScript which causes the error here :

Please help

```js
const wrapperSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
    const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

    const wrapperLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper span");

    burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
        
            wrapper.classList.toggle("wrapper-active");


            window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
                if (event.target != wrapper && event.target != burger && event.target.parentNode != burger && event.target.parentNode != wrapper) {
                    wrapper.classList.remove("wrapper-active");
                    burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
                }
            });


            //Animate Links
            wrapperLinks.forEach((link, index) => {

                if (link.style.animation) {   //if the animantion took place do nothing else do it
                    link.style.animation = "";
                } else {

                    link.style.animation = `wrapperLinkFade  0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.2}s`;
                }
            });


            //Burger Animation
            burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
        });

    }


wrapperSlide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a *new* `mouseup` event listener every time `burger` gets clicked.  Meaning the second time you click it, if you click outside, you will call

```
burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
```

twice, which obviously will cause issues.

Comment: i'm sorry but i still don't get it how do i fix it

Comment: either remove the event listener when the burger is closed, or add the event listener outside of the onclick handler (but then you'll have to change the logic to ignore the click if the menu is not open)

Comment: any idea how could i remove the event listener when the burger is closed ?